# Anaconda/Jupyter notebook/500 : Internal Server Error/windows 10/python3

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

I am learning data science with python and R, in my first course i downloaded python3, R and Rstudio and in the current course i am learning using jupyter and downloaded anaconda to handle jupyter notebook. when i tried to convert .ipyth file to PDF i ran into the following error message

```
nbconvert failed: PDF creating failed, captured latex output:
Failed to run "xelatex .\notebook.tex -quiet" command:
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! Undefined control sequence.
<*> .\notebook
              .tex -quiet
? 
! Emergency stop.
<*> .\notebook
              .tex -quiet
No pages of output.
Transcript written on ?.
```

Appreciate your support taking in consideration that i am new to programming

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's very little maintenance of LaTeX in nbconvert -- LaTeX conversions are a complex beast and there's not someone keeping it fed overtime for all the many edge cases and build tool changes.

There is a new webpdf conversion using chromium to generate PDF files coming in 6.0, which trades off some of the flexibility of xelatex / pandoc for consistency with web renderings (and a new optional dependency).

*(source: GitHub)*

The maintainers are trying to get the last of issues resolved for a final release our of alpha for 6.0. There's just not many of us with a lot of free time to contribute.

BTW what worked for me is to first download the .ipynb file as ".Tex" file and then converting that .Tex file into .pdf

Answer (score 0):

Open cmd and run the following code there:

```
pip install nbconvert==5.4.1
```

This solved my issue.

P.S. you may try the latest version.

Source: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3629#issuecomment-482692594